# Finding the region surrounded by light emitted from the vertices of a triangle through construction

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> P, Q and R represent the positions of three radio beacons. P is 450 km from Q, Q is 475 km from R, and R is 300 km P. Signals from P have a range of 300 km, Q has a range of 350 km and R has a range of 200 km. Shade the region in which all three signals can be received. Measure the shortest distance from Q to this region.

Sorry for the confusing title, I don't know the terminology used to describe these types of questions.

Here is my work on Geogebra: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/gsxvrgzs. The distance I got is 275 km.

Here is the book's answer:
[image]

My question: What is causing this difference between my and the book's results? My guess is that the book's diagram is misrepresenting something (or I'm wrong myself).

Edit: I left out a really integral part of the question, sorry.

Comment: What are the coordinates of the three beacons?

Comment: Sorry for the silly mistake, added @amd.

Comment: $Q$ looks like it’s misplaced in the book’s diagram. The radius of the circle at $R$ should be less than half the distance $QR$, and the radius of the circle at $Q$ should be about 3/4 of that distance.

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess this also explains the difference between the shortest distances.